# regex php look ahead number

Tags: php, regex

stackers!

I have been trying to figure this out for some time but no luck.
`(.*?(?:\.|\?|!))(?: |$)`

the above pattern is capturing and breaking all sentences in a paragraph with ending punctuation.
example

1. Today is the greatest. You are the greatest.

The match comes back with three

```
Match {  
  1.    
  Today is the greatest.   
  You are the greatest.   
}
```

However I am trying to get it to not break when there is a number with a period and would like to see the following match instead:

```
Match {  
  1.Today is the greatest.   
  You are the greatest.   
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: So you got lots of sentences and want to get them separated - delimited by `.` (dot)?
And in some sentences are such `1.` or `2.` that breaks the pattern?

Comment: Yes that is it exactally

Comment: I have come up with the following ^(?=\d\s?\.\s?)(.)+$ but still it is not complete

Comment: Another idea to use preg_split: [`preg_split('~[.!?](?<!\d.)\s+~', $str)`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkHdUE8hJD8lsVIhs1ihJCNVIb0oNbEktbhETyEyv1QhsSgVVVTdmouLq6AoM68kvkijoCg1Pb64ICezREO9LlpP0T5Ww95GMSZFTzOmWLtOXUcBZImmJlDL//8A) be aware eg. `Mr.` and so on. It requires *natural language processing*, to tokenize into sentences accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```php
.*?[.?!](?=(?<!\d\.)\s+|\s*$)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Z9B7ws/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [.?!]                    any character of: '.', '?', '!'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```